# C# check XmlNode value attribute

Tags: c#, xml

I wrote this code to check if a XmlNode has a value, but when I run it crash always on the !=null.
It is strange because this solution is well known.

```
private static void TraverseNodes(XmlNodeList nodes)
{
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    {

        if (!node.HasChildNodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(node.Name + " " + node.Attributes["id"].Value);
        }
        if (node.Attributes["SplitCombinationOperator"].Value != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(node.Name + " " + node.Attributes["SplitCombinationOperator"].Value);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(node.Name);
        }

        TraverseNodes(node.ChildNodes);
    }
}
```

The error is the following:
**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Comment: The SplitCombinationOperator may not exist, while your code assumes the "Value" property will be available, in any case.

Answer (score 1):

You should check for null values something like this:

```
node.Attributes["SplitCombinationOperator"] != null &&
node.Attributes["SplitCombinationOperator"].Value != null
```

Otherwise you will get `NullReferenceException` when `node.Attributes["SplitCombinationOperator"]` is null while trying to access its `Value` property.

Comment: Good, now I understand.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to check whether the attribute indexer itself returns null:

```
if (node.Attributes["SplitCombinationOperator"] != null)
```

Currently, that's returning null, and you're dereferencing it for the `Value` property - hence the exception. Note that you're also assuming there'd an `id` property, which may not be a good idea.

(You don't need to check whether `Value` itself is null - if the attribute exists, the value is non-null. Even if it's empty, you'll get an empty string rather than a null reference.)

Comment: I was figuring out why it was not working, but this explanation made it very clear.